# Why is date being formatted with a dot (period) after month abbreviation in en_AU locale?

Tags: java, tomcat

Java 1.8 Apache Tomcat 8.5.55

My server-side date parsing code:

```
            Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
            String lang = locale.getDisplayLanguage();
            String country = locale.getDisplayCountry();
            System.out.println(lang);
            System.out.println(country);
            
            LocalDate localDate1 = LocalDate.of(2023, 4, 10);
            
            ZoneId zone = ZoneId.systemDefault();
            Instant atStartOfDay = localDate1.atStartOfDay(zone).toInstant();
            String format = Constants.Format.user_dmy_df.get().format(Date.from(atStartOfDay));
            System.out.println(format);
```

Note:

```
public class Constants{
    public static class Format{
        public static final ThreadLocal<DateFormat> user_dmy_df = new ThreadLocal<DateFormat>() {
            @Override
            protected DateFormat initialValue() {
                return new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The output:

```
English
Australia
10-Apr.-2023
```

Why is there a period after the month abbreviation? This isn't AU formatting.  When I run the same code locally in a unit test (also en_AU) there is no period.

Comment: See https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8208487 and the linked bugs

Comment: wow @tgdavies how obscure!  Thanks

Comment: Exactly what version of Java 8 are you using? From what JDK vendor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use only *java.time*

Your code is needlessly mixing the terribly flawed legacy date-time classes with their replacement, the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Never use `Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`, `DateFormat`, etc.

## Sources of locale data

Most vendors of Java 8 include the [Unicode Consortium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_Consortium)’s [*Common Locale Data Repository (CLDR)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Locale_Data_Repository) as an alternate source of localization data. See [*Internationalization Enhancements in JDK 8*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/enhancements.8.html) by Oracle Corp.

In Java 8 and earlier, a limited set of locale data was always included, much less detailed than the CLDR.

A third set of possible locale data is the host [OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system).

Given the [bug](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8208487) mentioned [by tgdavies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76106437/why-is-date-being-formatted-with-a-dot-period-after-month-abbreviation-in-en-a#comment134220092_76106437), I suspect you might resolve your issue by using one source of data versus the others.

Of course I cannot know which is in use by your app now. In Java 8, the limited legacy JDK-specific locale data is used by default. But you can switch to using CLDR. This switch may or may not already be set in your app.

To switch, see the Oracle document linked above. To quote:

> To select the desired locale data source, use the `java.locale.providers` system property, listing the data sources in the preferred order. For example:
>
> `java.locale.providers=HOST,SPI,CLDR,JRE`
>
> The default behavior is equivalent to the following setting:
>
> `java.locale.providers=JRE,SPI`

I suggest experimenting with each of those sources of locale data to see if your problem occurs with particular ones.

### Example code

I tried switching locale data sources using the following code.  I could not reproduce your issue with the unexpected FULL STOP character. I used Java 8 Update 372 provided by Azul Systems in their *Zulu* JDK product.

I assume that setting `"java.locale.providers"` as a system property takes effect immediately. But I do not know for sure how that works.

```java
System.out.println( System.getProperty( "java.version" ) );
System.out.println( System.getProperty( "java.locale.providers" ) );

LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of( 2023 , 4 , 10 );
Locale locale = new Locale( "en" , "AU" );
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MMM-yyyy" ).withLocale( locale );
System.out.println( "Default localDate.format( f ) = " + localDate.format( f ) );
for ( String provider : Arrays.asList( "SPI" , "HOST" , "CLDR" , "JRE" ) )
{
    System.setProperty( "java.locale.providers" , provider );
    System.out.println( System.getProperty( "java.locale.providers" ) + " = " + localDate.format( f ) );
}
```

When run:

```
1.8.0_372
null
Default localDate.format( f ) = 10-Apr-2023
SPI = 10-Apr-2023
HOST = 10-Apr-2023
CLDR = 10-Apr-2023
JRE = 10-Apr-2023
```

---

By the way… In Java 9+, the default source of locale data changed to the CLDR. See [JEP 252: Use CLDR Locale Data by Default](https://openjdk.org/jeps/252).